# Can't create job on GCP Cloud Scheduler

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I try to create a job in the GCP Cloud Scheduler I get this error:

> {"error":{"code":7,"message":"The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission \"iam.serviceAccounts.actAs\" for the resource \"[my service account]\" (or the resource may not exist)."}}

When I enabled the GCP Cloud Scheduler the service account was created (and I can see it in my accounts list). I have verified that it has the "Cloud Scheduler Service Agent" role.

I am logged in as an Owner of our project. It is when I try to create the job that I get this error. I tried to add the "Service Account User" to my principal account, but to no avail.

Does anyone know if I have to add any additional permissions? Or if I have to allow my principal to act (impersonate?) this service account in some way?

Many thanks.
Ben

Answer (score 4):

Ok I figured this out. The documentation is (sort of, in my view) clear if you read it in a certain way / know how GCP IAM works.

You actually need *two* service accounts. You need one that you set up yourself (can be whatever name you like and doesn't require any special permissions) and you also need the one for Cloud Scheduler itself.

Don't confuse the two. And use the one that you created when specifying the service account to generate the OAuth / OICD tokens.

Comment: sorry, but your answer isn't clear to me.
I'm having the similar error in one project (while in another jobs are created without issues with same commands and I'm an Owner in both projects). And I don't create any additional service accounts just use the default compute engine one.