# Cloud scheduler isn't accepting my created service account for scheduled jobs

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud, job-scheduling

I'm getting the exact same error as described here: [Can't create job on GCP Cloud Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58480834/cant-create-job-on-gcp-cloud-scheduler)

and I have been using a service user that I myself created and gave the appropriate permissions. and fully stripping and restoring those permissions yielded no results either.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud scheduler itself must have a service account [1] which is Cloud scheduler Service Agent role [2], we need to check that this particular role has for the Cloud scheduler service account. Also the document [1] could be helpful for better understanding.

Also, please check the documentation [3] for supported regions and If the project does not have an App Engine app, we need to create one.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/http-target-auth#setting_up_the_service_account

[2] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles

[3] https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/#supported_regions